# how can i do empty Arraylist in immediate window in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how can i do empty Arraylist in immediate window in asp.net

Comment: What do you mean by "do" an empty ArrayList? What does ASP.NET have to do with it, if you're interested in the Immediate window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I'm making a big assumption here about your requirements, but it sounds like you want to empty an arraylist whilst debugging your ASP.NET app?

Put a breakpoint in your ASP.NET where the arraylist is accessible. Then in the immediate window:

```
? arraylist.Clear()
```

and press return.